# How to validate SWT form?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

```
Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NULL);
    label1.setText("Enter the Password ");
    text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.PASSWORD);
    text1.setText("");
    text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {


        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (!text5.getText().isEmpty()) {
                setPageComplete(false);

            }
        }

    });
```

hi, i am creating form using SWT in eclipse can anyone tell me how to validate that form entry above is the sample code of that..actually i want to validate password field it should be minimum length of 6.How to do this please reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Message Manager, as described in **[Eclipse Form](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Forms33/index.html)** article.

> As discussed above, support has been added to show messages in the form heading. To make the handling of multiple messages within a form easier, a message manager has been made available in 3.3 through the `IManagedForm` interface. The manager is provided as an interface (`IMessageManager`).
>
> The message manager will track multiple messages for the user at a time and will show text-based on the most severe message present at any given time (`ERROR > WARNING > INFO`).
> It also provides the ability, when adding a message, to associate a control with it. If this is done, the message manager will decorate the specified control with an image appropriate to the message type.

[image]

---

Regarding the specific issue, you can look at similar implementations of this problem, like the [`org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.wizards.ConfigurationWizardMainPage` class](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/team/internal/ccvs/ui/wizards/ConfigurationWizardMainPage.java.htm):

```
// Password
createLabel(g, CVSUIMessages.ConfigurationWizardMainPage_password);
passwordText = createPasswordField(g);
passwordText.addListener(SWT.Modify, listener);

Listener listener = new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.widget == passwordText) {
       // check its length
```

Comment: Can you please give the solution in the reference of above problem...i.e password field validation.